# What does "<nickname, callsign or characteristic> out" mean?

Tags: slang

What does "smartass out" mean?

This is a verb? (I know that "smartass" means, but)

I guess it means that "He pretends to be smart, and tries to show it in all ways". Yeah, im right?

Can you give more examples with a similar meaning (words with 'out' at the end) ?

*found it in this comment:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mxXJEUoVqlo&lc=UggcoBUmM13hA3gCoAEC*

Full text:

```
"These are also quite big pieces of paper!
A1 double the size of A2.
A2 double the size of A3.
A3 double the size of A4.
and so on

Smartass out!"
```

Comment: You didn't link to a comment, only a video. Can you put the full text of the comment in your question so we can read it without going to YT?

Comment: @AzorAhai I don't get, why YouTube don't point comment. Anyway, i edit the question

Comment: That's not even really what a "smartass" is but ok, thanks for the edit

Comment: @AzorAhai i thought it may be useful for those people who will search answer like i get here

Comment: Nah, I was criticizing the YouTube commenter because that comment doesn't sound particularly "smartass" to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a sign-off. Notice that your example occurs at the end of a comment: "smartass out!"

In ham radio or peer-to-peer voice communications, it is protocol to signal when you are done speaking so that you can clear the air waves for the other to speak. How? You say "over." When the conversation is done, you say another signal: "[over and out](https://writingexplained.org/idiom-dictionary/over-and-out)" is a common idiom for this, though the proper convention is "[out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiotelephony_procedure)." This form of "out" is fairly widespread in slang.

The structure here is "(*name or callsign*) out!"  "Smartass" is self-referential: the commenter is calling herself or himself a smartass, and saying that the smartass (they) are leaving.

Comment: Damn, thanks man! Now I get it!
But can someone give me another example of slang of my guessing meaning...
Google tranclate give me "show off", but Is there a more tough (and\or slang) example?
Thanks!

Comment: @lazzlo Please don't ask supplementary questions in comments. *Smartass* could indeed mean "show-off" but that doesn't have much to do with *out*.